# Change Jupyter notebook from right to left

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have jupyter notebook but for some reason everything appears from right to left:

[image]

One of the outcomes of this is that the tables are also appears from right to left and it is hard to read.

How can I solve it and shift it to right side?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to toggle the RTL layout. Go to your command pallete (the keyboard shaped thingy) and look for "toggle RTL layout". This would fix your problem. Happens when default language is arabic or so. https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/10980